# What controls the name of the Back to App Title

Tags: ios9

When you switch to another app be it due to a notification or tapping on a link, the Status bar displays a button that takes you back to where you were in the previous app:

[image: Back to App Title]

- Can I control that name?
- Must it be the same as the Springboard?
- Why does it sometimes appears a **Back to App Title**?